# ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext error

Tags: java, spring

Hi I am completely new to Java, so sorry if my question may sound a bit stupid.

I am following a tutorial on hibernate and i am trying to get the context definition files from the file system.

```
ApplicationContext ctx  = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(
        new String[] { "conf/rssWebApplication-services.xml",
        "conf/rssWebApplication-data-hibernate.xml" });
```

But i get the following error:

```
found   : org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext
required: org.jboss.weld.context.ApplicationContext
        ApplicationContext ctx  = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(
                new String[] { "conf/rssWebApplication-services.xml",
```

Any idea what is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your import of `ApplicationContext` is wrong - fix it, to point to spring's `ApplicationContext`. (Currently, it is from the Weld framework). So:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
```

instead of

```
org.jboss.weld.context.ApplicationContext
```